# How to convert "2011-2012" to datetime object in mongodb in python?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hi I am saving year as string as "2011-2012" in db, i want to convert it to datetime object and save it in datetime object like "datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0)-datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0)"?
can you please help me

Comment: please clarify: you want to create a date range based on the years found in strings like "2011-2012"?

Comment: I think you cannot save datetime range in DB. My suggestion would be store the start and end of range separately.

Comment: Or is it a string containing the date range? Please clarify.

Comment: @MrFuppes, yes Fuppes

Answer (score 0):

you could use `rrule` from the `dateutil` package:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, MONTHLY

# input string:
years = '2011-2012'

# map to integer:
years = tuple(map(int, years.split('-')))

# obtain a datetime object for the starting year and the total years:
start_year = datetime(years[0], 1, 1)
total_years = years[1]-years[0]

# use rrule to generate a monthly range:
monthrange = []
dt_range = list(rrule(freq=MONTHLY, count=total_years*12+1, dtstart=start_year))

# [datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 1, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2011, 3, 1, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2011, 4, 1, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 1, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 1, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 1, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 1, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2011, 9, 1, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 1, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 1, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 1, 0, 0),
#  datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: @MahimaK: by the way, if you happen to work with `pandas`, you could also use something like `pd.date_range(*years.split('-'), freq='MS')`.